# processing notifications for image upload to docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to write an endpoint for docker-registry which will return me the name of docker-image which is modified recently (pushed to private docker registry[version 2.1 or 2.3]). I configured notifications endpoint in the docker registry and I am able to get notifications as and when an image is pushed to the private docker registry. However, I don't see a tag related to the image in the response, plus there are 3-4 push notifications (maybe for each layer) for a single docker image. 
Here is the snippet of what I am getting:-
http://pastebin.com/B4jDR4q2

Can someone plese help me out in understanding how I should go ahead to figure out the image-name which is recently being added (along with tag version)? Also, how should I process the notifications received to consider the different notifications as a single update? Any pointers for these would be really helpful.

Thanks.